# In swift, failing converting date format, but cannot use ISO8601DateFormatter

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

I fail getting 'start' value, tested many variants and formatters. For production reasons cannot use ISO8601DateFormatter.

this code is part of creating appointment on the calendar, so I need start as start date/hour of the appointment.

Above all, I need to understand why this last line of code fails after I tried to convert date:

event.startDate is my 'start' but cannot set it since fails converting date

```
   guard let url = URL(string: "calshow:\(event.startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)") else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
```

my code:

> date0

is a Date I get from API, with value 2021-07-28 00:00:00 +0000

my updated code for creating event on calendar

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
            let date = dateFormatter.string(from: date0)
            
            
            if let startTime = hours.from,
               let startDate = date.concats(startTime),
               let start = self.shortTimeFormatter.date(from: startDate) {
                event.startDate = start
                event.addAlarm(EKAlarm(absoluteDate: start.dayBefore))
                event.addAlarm(EKAlarm(absoluteDate: start.halfHourBefore))
                event.endDate = start.hourAfter
            }
            
            if let endTime = hours.to,
               let endDate = date.concats(endTime),
               let end = self.shortTimeFormatter.date(from: endDate) {
                event.endDate = end
            }
```

concats code

```
  func concats(_ string: String, withSeparator separator: String? = "") -> String? {
        return [self, string].compactMap{ $0 }.joined(separator: separator! + " ")
    }
```

ShortDateTimeFormatter

```
public class ShortDateTimeFormatter: DateFormatter {
    
    override public init() {
        super.init()
        self.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    }
    
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? What does your code output? What output do you expect? Your question is missing a bunch of things here, not gonna lie.

Comment: you are right, added more info

Comment: @biggreentree show the date strings that you are trying to parse

Comment: added what I see on console

Comment: Please **read** the date string. All formatters containing slashes and `T` can be discarded at once. And the format starts clearly with the year. [Here](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) is the table with all specifiers.

Comment: I tried adding yyyy/MM/dd formatter, but conversion fails all the way.

Comment: If I undrerstand the code correctly, you have a date, encode it to string using a bunch of formatters, then concat a random string, and then you try to parse it with a whole different format? How do you expect it to work?

Comment: I have a date, wich I try to format, then concat an hour, then use result  for creating a starting date. the foor loop, Is there only for testing.

Comment: @vadian I thought that I format formatter in the way I need the Date to be formatted. Is this wrong? anyway, even with ["yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"] code fails

Comment: @Sulthan how should I proceed in your opinion? I'm clearly not getting the point.

Comment: @biggreentree You are appending time with seconds, your short formatter doesn't understand seconds.
In my opinion is wrong to append time manually anyway. Create a correct `Date` and format it to string, without any concatenation.

Comment: concatenation is not my will, but a function I should use, the more, I get from any the date you see, and the hour in form of a string, how could convert it to .hour and .minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the code you get a `Date` without the time portion and you want to add the time in string format `"HH:mm:ss"`.

`Calendar` can do that. You don't need to convert the `Date` to `String` and back to `Date`.

First create a function which converts the time string to `Int` components

```
func timeComponents(from string: String) -> (Int, Int, Int)? {
    let comps = string.components(separatedBy: ":")
    guard comps.count == 3,
          let hr = Int(comps[0]),
          let mn = Int(comps[1]),
          let sc = Int(comps[2])
          else { return nil }
    return (hr, mn, sc)
}
```

Then add the time to `date0` with `date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:)`

```
if let (hr, mn, sc) = timeComponents(from: "08:30:00") {
    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: hr, minute: mn, second: sc, of: date0)
}
```

---

Or with `DateComponents`

```
func timeComponents(from string: String) -> DateComponents? {
    let comps = string.components(separatedBy: ":")
    guard comps.count == 3,
          let hr = Int(comps[0]),
          let mn = Int(comps[1]),
          let sc = Int(comps[2])
          else { return nil }
    return DateComponents(hour: hr, minute: mn, second: sc)
}

if let components = timeComponents(from: "08:30:00") {
    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: date0, wrappingComponents: false)
}
```

Comment: ok, I updated my question so you can see how I'm  using date and hour for creating event calendar and al alarms, I think the I need anyway some conversion

Comment: As far as I can see you can everything with my suggestion without converting the date back and forth.

Comment: @vadian `date(bySettingHour` is a bit problematic due to the `matchingPolicy` which is set to `nextTime` by default and can also change higher components. It would be probably safer to get date components, change them and then convert to `Date` again.

Comment: tanks to both of you for your help and clarifications @vadian,  #Sulthan

Comment: but, @vadian you can tell my why the appointment to 08:30 is set on simulato's calendar to 10:30 am?

Comment: It's a time zone issue. Is your time zone UTC+0200?

Comment: I think so since I'm in Italy. only a simulator issue?

Comment: Auguri per il campionato europeo  No, it's a general issue. A `Date` instance doesn't have a time zone, if the date you receive is supposed to be in the local time zone you have to adjust the time zone in `Calendar` or the date formatter.

Comment: Grazie per il campionato :D, so I just need something like this before your code 'var calendar = Calendar.current
                calendar.timeZone = .current'

Comment: When you `print(date0)` what do you get?

Comment: 2021-07-20 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: This date is in UTC (if it was in your time zone you would get 2021-07-19 22:00:00). So either you have to adjust the time zone when you receive the date from the API (most likely you get also a string or a time interval) or when you are going to display the date set the time zone of the date formatter to UTC.

Comment: I see, but starting from your solution, I'm not using formatters, end even setting directly timezone is not working, but this is a different question so if you have the time, I made a brand new question, with more info about the situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68406244/how-to-update-time-zone-for-using-it-in-my-calendar-correctly

Comment: You should add in the other question how you decode the JSON, this is the crucial point.