# how to update TIME ZONE for using it in my calendar correctly?

Tags: swift, date, timezone

Issue here is that while from API I get date in this form

> Foundation.Date   2021-07-20 00:00:00 UTC

I successfully add hours, with I get start hour from API in form of "08:30:00" with gives me the value for **start** (but same issue about the end date) this way:

> Foundation.Date   2021-07-20 08:30:00 UTC

but, when I get to calendar, the events are set to 10:30 AM, how could I correct the TIME ZONE?

I tested things like

```
let calendar = Calendar()
calendar.timezone = .current
```

but did not work

example from response

```
{
  "data": {
    "appointments": [
      {
        "date": "2021-07-20T00:00:00.000Z",
        "time": {
          "from": "08:30:00",
          "to": "09:30:00"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

my code

```
func onSynchronize(detailInfo: AppointmentDetail) {
        
    
        let appointment = detailInfo
        
        let fakeAddress = "fake address"
        let fakeLocality = "Alderaan"
        
        
        let store = EKEventStore()
        store.requestAccess(to: .event) {(granted, error) in
            if !granted { return }
            let event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
            event.title = "my title"
            
            guard let date0 = appointment.date else { return }
            guard let hours = appointment.time else { return }
            guard let host = appointment.host else { return }
            
            if let componentsFrom = self.timeComponentsFromHourInString(from: hours.from) {
                if let start = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: componentsFrom, to: date0, wrappingComponents: false) {
                    event.startDate = start
                    event.addAlarm(EKAlarm(absoluteDate: start.dayBefore))
                    event.addAlarm(EKAlarm(absoluteDate: start.halfHourBefore))
                    event.endDate = start.hourAfter
                }
            }
            
            if let componentsTo = self.timeComponentsFromHourInString(from: hours.to) {
                if let end = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: componentsTo, to: date0, wrappingComponents: false) {
                    event.endDate = end
                }
            }
            
           
 
            event.location = fakeAddress.concats(fakeLocality, withSeparator: "-")
            
            
            event.url = URL(string: BanksUtils.appLocalizeString(forKey: "url"))
            if let managerDescription = host.managerDescription,
               let manager = BanksUtils.localizeString(forKey: "handledBy").concats(managerDescription.capitalized),
               let description = appointment.requestorDescription,
               let reason = BanksUtils.localizeString(forKey: "reason").concats(description.capitalized) {
                event.notes = manager + "\n" + reason
            } else {
                if let description = appointment.requestorDescription {
                    event.notes = BanksUtils.localizeString(forKey: "reason").concats(description.capitalized)
                }
            }
           
            let structuredLocation = EKStructuredLocation(title: fakeAddress)
            structuredLocation.geoLocation = self.location
            event.structuredLocation = structuredLocation
            event.calendar = store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
            
            do {
                try store.save(event, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
            } catch {
                Log.logger.error("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
            
            guard let url = URL(string: "calshow:\(event.startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)") else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
            
        
        }
    }



///Allows to get  HH:MM:SS from an hour in form of a string
func timeComponentsFromHourInString(from string: String) -> DateComponents? {
    let comps = string.components(separatedBy: ":")
    guard comps.count == 3,
          let hr = Int(comps[0]),
          let mn = Int(comps[1]),
          let sc = Int(comps[2])
          else { return nil }
    return DateComponents(hour: hr, minute: mn, second: sc)
}
```

Comment: A `Foundation.Date` has no timezone information associated with it, so "change the timezone of a `Date`" is simply not a thing you can do. You might want to reconsider your design if you think you need to do that.

Comment: The JSON date format is clearly UTC. You could adjust the time zone if you remove the trailing Z in the date string while decoding the JSON with a `custom` date decoding strategy.

Comment: i agree with @vadian just print date to string it will give you date regarding your timzone. just try and let me know.

Comment: I get printed from date0 2021-07-20 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: Are the times supposed to be the times in the local timezone or UTC?